# Validate commit message contains Jira Ticket Number when squash merge from GitHub webUI

Tags: github, jira, git-merge, pull-request, git-squash

When doing a squash merge, following a successful Pull Request, on github I would like to validate that the squash merge commit message contains a Jira ticket number. If it does not the squash merge should fail until a proper commit message is entred by the user.

Right now this needs to be done manually and sometimes I forget to include the ticket number I would like an automatic way to make sure I don't forget to do it.

1. I know that I can use hooks locally to force a Jira Ticket number but I dont care about how the user work on his on branch. I really just want the protected branch commits to all start with a Jira ticket
2. I do not have github entreprise so I can't use a pre-receive hook.
3. I have look into github action but not sure this is the proper way to go.

Some Reference but no solutions:

1. [Ensure github PR squash merge commit comments contain issue ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55006426/ensure-github-pr-squash-merge-commit-comments-contain-issue-id)
2. https://github.com/github/feedback/discussions/8688